# Issue when using ticks option on h-axis: google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I am using google chart's combo stacked bar. I want to display explicit values for h-axis, so I used ticks option. But, after using this option, my graph is displaying all bar values at once along the h-axis. But, I want to limit the bars to let's say 5 at a time and display the rest dynamically by sliding the charRangeFilter. The bars are almost appearing as straight lines when I use ticks option as shown in the image. Could some help me in resolving this issue? Any help is highly appreciated

Below is the code for the chart options

```
let hTicks = new  Array<Date>(); // I already populated this array with Dates

let chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({     
                'chartType': 'ComboChart',     
                'containerId': 'chartRangeFilter_chart_div',      
                'options': { . 
                    // Use the same chart area width as the control for .  axis alignment.  
                    'width': '100%',      
                    'height': '100%',      
                    'hAxis': { 'title': 'DATES', 'gridlines': { 'color': 'transparent' }, 'ticks': hTicks, 'slantedText': true, 'slantedTextAngle': hTicks.length <= 10 ? 45 : 90 },      
                    'legend': 'none',      
                    'vAxis': { 'title': 'CABINS', 'viewWindow': { 'min': 0, 'max': (Number(cabinTotal) * 1.5) } },      
                    'seriesType': 'bars',      
                    'chartArea': { 'height': '50%', 'width': '85%' },      
                    'bar': { 'groupWidth': '15%' },      
                    'series': { 4: { 'type': 'line' } },      
                    'isStacked': true,      
                    'colors': ['#95d631', '#d7d7d7', '#f44336',       '#00bcd4', '#ffc107']      
                }
```

Below are the charts

[Chart with Tick option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edWf2.png)                                                                                                                                                                                                [Chart Without Tick option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ARj.png)

Comment: you'll need to set ticks to the values that should be displayed

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat, I already set the ticks property with an array of dates value. The issue is all the bars are appearing at a time on the graph. I don't want this to happen. But, show them dynamically by sliding chartFilter Slider .

Comment: 'hAxis': { 'title': 'DATES', 'gridlines': { 'color': 'transparent' }, 'ticks': hTicks }. This is the code I added in chart options

Comment: you'll need to update the ticks dynamically...

Comment: Use of the 'ticks' option currently means that all those ticks will be displayed, so if you want (need?) to use this option when also using a chart range filter, then you will have to change the ticks option each time the range filter changes.  We should probably have an option to NOT expand the view window when the ticks option is used; and it would probably be better to do that by default, or maybe always.

Comment: Hi @dlaliberte, do we an option to Not to Expand view window in Chart Options?

Comment: You can set the view window explicitly, which should override what the ticks option will trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating the ticks dynamically as the user slides the chartFilter